# Overcoming ambiguous field error in SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 4 tables and this query

```
SELECT tag.id, title
FROM tag
LEFT JOIN tag_map ON ( tag.id = tag_map.tag_id ) 
LEFT JOIN post ON ( post.id = post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game ON ( game.id = post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN video ON ( video.id = post_id ) 
WHERE tag_slug =  "blizzard"
ORDER BY tag_map.post_type
```

The problem in this query is that the 3 tables on the left join statement all have a title column. Because of this I'm getting the "Column 'title' in field list is ambiguous" error.

How can I handle this so that the query shows the related title field for each row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the additional information supplied in a comment to another response, it appears that the a DIFFERENT title field needs to be selected depending on the post_type, with post_types corresponding to the post, game, and video tables.

I'll assume that post_type is a one character text column.

You can do that in two ways, with LEFT JOIN or UNION.

```
SELECT tag.id, 
CASE post_type 
   WHEN 'P' THEN post.title 
   WHEN 'V' THEN video.title 
   WHEN 'G' THEN game.title
END CASE
FROM tag
LEFT JOIN tag_map ON ( tag.id = tag_map.tag_id ) 
LEFT JOIN post ON ( post.id = post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game ON ( game.id = post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN video ON ( video.id = post_id ) 
WHERE tag_slug =  "blizzard"
ORDER BY tag_map.post_type
```

However, a UNION solution might be clearer:

```
SELECT tag.id, post_type, title 
  FROM tag_map INNER JOIN post ON tag_map.post_id = post.id
UNION ALL
SELECT tag.id, post_type, title 
  FROM tag_map INNER JOIN game ON tag_map.post_id = game.id
UNION ALL
SELECT tag.id, post_type, title 
  FROM tag_map INNER JOIN video ON tag_map.post_id = video.id
WHERE tag_slug =  "blizzard"
ORDER BY tag_map.post_type
```

(Note, I simplified the answers slightly because it's not clear to me the relation between tag and tag_map, you might need to introduce both tables into the SELECTS).

Comment: Thanks this works for me. One more question. Is there performance difference between these two queries.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing your final queries and knowing the complete structure of each table joined, and what the indexes are.  Even then it will depend on the nature of the values in the indexed columns.  However, there's no obvious reason that one should be faster than the other.  The only way of knowing is to benchmark on real data and use EXPLAIN to gain insight into how the engine is choosing to execute the two queries.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify which table you want `title` to come from.  Taking a guess that title will be in `game` you would need to specify `game.title`.

If I were you I'd start looking into splitting this down a bit using temporary tables.  Although theres nothing wrong with 4 joins it does tend to start getting confusing.

**Example temp table:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Yaks (
YakID int,
YakName char(30) )
```

In your scenario you would create a temp table and then fill it with an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` based on individual joins so at the end all you have to do is `SELECT * FROM @temptable`

Comment: I am not very familiar with temporary tables. Can you give an example?

Comment: I've provided an example - not the best I know.  If you were to show me how your tables are structured I should be able to help you more

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
tag.id, 
tag_map.title as tagmaptitle,
post.title as posttitle,
game.title as gametitle,
video.title as viedotitle,
FROM tag
LEFT JOIN tag_map ON ( tag.id = tag_map.tag_id ) 
LEFT JOIN post ON ( post.id = post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game ON ( game.id = post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN video ON ( video.id = post_id ) 
WHERE tag_slug =  "blizzard"
ORDER BY tag_map.post_type
```

Comment: I tried this approach. However this query returns many unnecessary data. For example when you get a row for video that row will contain useless post and game titles. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @Sinan, just leave out post.title and game.title in the list of columns.

Comment: @Larry thats not about it. The right field could be one of the three for each row depending on the post_type

Comment: @Sinan: Aha.  That's not clear from your question.  I'll post an answer.

Comment: I am getting the same problem with the query "select case when a.position < b.position then busid else null end as busid from (select busid,position from route where routid=$start) a join (select busid,position from route where routid=$end) b on a.busid = b.busid" getting error of unambiguous field busid, What can I do

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal you should post that as your own question and give more detail